# Facebook Messenger App - Login Report

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, messages, facebook

I have a question regarding the Facebook Messenger App regarding the multiple login on different devices and some kind of report of that.

So here's what happened (I'll make it short):
I have an iPhone and an Android tablet, but I lent the tablet to one of my friends for 2 weeks. Now I am pretty sure that he read all my incoming messages because on my iPhone they were already shown as "Read by me" when I opened the Messenger app and these are the only two devices where I check my messages.

I asked him, but of course he said that he didn't read them.

Now I would like to know if there is any chance that I can see when I used the app to read messages and especially where (so that I can exclude hacking), so basically some kind of report for every read message or at least a usage report with data about my account.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: The Messanger app shows time and date stamps for when conversations occurred.  When messages are sent within a relatively short time period, only the first one shows the stamp.  Otherwise, I think that's the best you'll be able to do.

Comment: did you try to change your password to exclude hacking?

Answer (score 1):

From Facebook Settings (on a PC), click the 'download a copy of your Facebook data' link.  Included[image] will be a list of login activity, amongst everything else